# Get text from image with ImageMagick and Tesseract

Tags: imagemagick, tesseract

I wanted to know if anyone has ever used Tesseract with ImageMagick to get precise text from image. My main concern is with the small font texts present in an image (or some text that are not clearly visible). The only way I am able to retrieve those unclear texts are by modifying the image by ImageMagick like - by scaling the image, sometimes cropping the image....

I wanted to know if someone has integrated ImageMagick and Tesseract to create even powerful tool?

Answer (score 4):

Till now, I have come up with a script that can search the text in the image... The script uses imagemagick and tesseract. The script is still under development, but you can look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978986/ocr-getting-text-from-image-using-tesseract-3-0-and-imagemagick-6-6-5)