# OCR - Getting text from image using tesseract 3.0 and imagemagick 6.6.5

Tags: linux, imagemagick, tesseract

I am trying to build a shell script that allows me to search for text in an image. Based on the text, the script will try its best to get the text from the image. I wanted your input on this as this script seems to work with most images, but not those images where the text font color is similar to smaller-surroundings around the text.

```
# !/bin/bash
# 
# imt-ocr.sh is image magick tessearc OCR tool that is used for finding out text in image
#
# Arguments:
# 1     -- image filename (with path)
# 2     -- text to search in image      (default to '')
# 3     -- occurence of text            (default to 1)
# Usage:
# imt-ocr.sh [image_filename] [text_to_search] [occurence]
#

image=$1
txt=$2
occurence=$3    # Default to 1
if [ "$occurence" == "" ]
then
        occurence=1
fi

get_major_color ()
# Returns the major color of an image with its hex value
#       Parameter:      Image filename (with path)
#       Return format:  Returns a string "hex_val_of_color major_color_name"
{
convert $1 -format %c histogram:info: > x.txt
cat x.txt | awk '{print $1}' > x1.txt
h=$(sort -n x1.txt | tail -1);
color_info=$(cat x.txt | grep "$h" | cut -d '#' -f2)
rm -rf x.txt x1.txt
echo "$color_info"
}


invert_color()
# Inverts the color hex value
#       Parameter:      Hex value to be inverted
#       Return format:  Returns in hex
{
input_color_hex=$1                                              # Input color's hex value
white_color_hex=FFFFFF                                          # White color's  hex vlaue
inv_color_hex=`echo $(printf '%06X\n' $((0x$white_color_hex - 0x$input_color_hex)))`
echo $inv_color_hex
}


start_scale=100
end_scale=300
increment_scale=100
tmp_img=dst.tif
attempt=1
for ((scale=$start_scale, attempt=$attempt; scale <= $end_scale ; scale=scale+$increment_scale, attempt++))
        do
                echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to $scale% in attempt #$attempt"
                convert $image -type Grayscale -scale $scale% $tmp_img
                tesseract $tmp_img OUT
                found_oc=$(grep -o "$txt" OUT.txt | wc -l)
                echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Found $found_oc occurence(s) of text '$txt' in attempt #$attempt"
                if [ $occurence -le $found_oc ] && [ $found_oc -ne 0 ]
                then
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Printing out the last text found on image"
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================"
                        cat OUT.txt
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================"
                        rm -rf $tmp_img OUT.txt
                        exit 1
                else
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Getting major color of image in attempt #$attempt"
                        color_info=`get_major_color $image`
                        true_color=$(echo $color_info | awk '{print $2}')
                        true_val=$(echo $color_info | awk '{print $1}')
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Major color of image is '$true_color' with hex value of $true_val in attempt #$attempt"

                        # Blur the image
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Bluring image in attempt #$attempt"
                        convert $tmp_img -blur 1x65535 $tmp_img

                        # Flip the color
                        inverted_val=`invert_color $true_val`
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Inverting the major color of image from 0x$true_val to 0x$inverted_val in attempt #$attempt"
                        convert $tmp_img -fill \#$inverted_val -opaque \#$true_val $tmp_img

                        # Sharpen the image
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Sharpening image in attempt #$attempt"
                        convert $tmp_img -sharpen 1x65535 $tmp_img

                        # Find text
                        tesseract $tmp_img OUT
                        found_oc=$(grep -o "$txt" OUT.txt | wc -l)
                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Found $found_oc occurence(s) of text '$txt' in attempt #$attempt"
                        if [ "$found_oc" != "0" ]
                        then
                                if [ $occurence -le $found_oc ]
                                then
                                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: Printing out the last text found on image"
                                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================"
                                        cat OUT.txt
                                        echo "IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================"
                                        rm -rf $tmp_img OUT.txt
                                        exit 1
                                fi
                        fi
                fi

                rm -rf OUT.txt

        done

rm -rf $tmp_img
```

Here is a sample example with problem,
image (test.jpeg) http://www.igoipad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/03-Word-Collage-iPad.jpeg

```
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ sh imt-ocr.sh test.jpeg Common
IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to 100% in attempt #1
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Common' in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Getting major color of image in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Major color of image is 'grey96' with hex value of F5F5F5 in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Bluring image in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Inverting the major color of image from 0xF5F5F5 to 0x0A0A0A in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Sharpening image in attempt #1
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Common' in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to 200% in attempt #2
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 1 occurence(s) of text 'Common' in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Printing out the last text found on image
IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================
Settings M...
Text
Common words
Exclude numbers
word case
Theme & Layuul
Color theme
Fnnl
Word layout
Clrien lalion
7301
Lrmclsc ape
\u2018OTC
Ergl sw v.-ords >
li( `
I):Jntc1'\:1r\qa )
Landon Spring >
Hough Trad >
H3'fJ|1d :-Ialf >
H L

IMT-OCR-LOG: ======================================================
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ 
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$ sh imt-ocr.sh test.jpeg Portrait
IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to 100% in attempt #1
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Getting major color of image in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Major color of image is 'grey96' with hex value of F5F5F5 in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Bluring image in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Inverting the major color of image from 0xF5F5F5 to 0x0A0A0A in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Sharpening image in attempt #1
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #1
IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to 200% in attempt #2
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Getting major color of image in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Major color of image is 'grey96' with hex value of F5F5F5 in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Bluring image in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Inverting the major color of image from 0xF5F5F5 to 0x0A0A0A in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Sharpening image in attempt #2
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #2
IMT-OCR-LOG: Scaling image to 300% in attempt #3
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #3
IMT-OCR-LOG: Getting major color of image in attempt #3
IMT-OCR-LOG: Major color of image is 'grey96' with hex value of F5F5F5 in attempt #3
IMT-OCR-LOG: Bluring image in attempt #3
IMT-OCR-LOG: Inverting the major color of image from 0xF5F5F5 to 0x0A0A0A in attempt #3
IMT-OCR-LOG: Sharpening image in attempt #3
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
IMT-OCR-LOG: Found 0 occurence(s) of text 'Portrait' in attempt #3
[admin@ba-callgen image-magick-tesseract-processing]$
```

As you can see I can find text "common", but not "Portrait". The reason is because of the font color of the Portrait. Any help to improve this script...

I am using Centos 5.

Comment: The problem you describe isn't the only one. Some of the other words aren't correctly identified either. I would first try to get those correct, maybe that would help with the 'Portrait' search as well...

Comment: Friendly advice: you should consider to 'accept' and/or 'upvote' more of the answers you received to your previous questions. That would increase the willingness of people to put effort thinking abou your problems...

Comment: BTW, on my system (Mac OS X Lion, with tesseract v3.01 and ImageMagick v6.7.8-3 2012-07-30 Q16) my recognition results are better than the ones you quoted. For example: I do get `Orientation` where you get `Clrien lalion`... Which tesseract version is on your Centos 5? Which ImageMagick version?

Comment: Oh, I see the versions are mentioned in the headline. Never mind...

Comment: Thanks Kurt. I actually do accept and upvote  answers/comments... So, regarding the text parsing, it completely depends on how well the image has been formatted so that the tesseract can easily detect the text. Right now, the major concern is at only those places where the font of the text mixes up with the major background. For that, in my current implementation, I am trying to enlarge, blur, change the color... Thats the key logic!!

So, I have thought of an alternate solution that only works from a theoretical perspective. Please read the next comment...

Comment: The alternate solution is to separate the image based on blocks of colors. What I have noticed is that, if the tesseract is given only the image (cropped image) containing Portrait, it can easily detect it. So, idea is to separate the image based on blocks of color something similar to http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/separate/index.php, but I haven't be able to successfully implement this solution because the separation of image based on color is not easy... What do you think?

Comment: I understand... my questions are hard to answer I believe... Any case, I have tried to answer all of my own questions to best of my ability....

Comment: What is your real goal with this? *"Build a generic OCR script that recognizes whatever I throw at it, even multi-colored screenshots."* ?  Or rather: *"Build an OCR script that extracts texts from iPad screenshots using the typical iPad colors."* ??

Comment: Ok, the real goal is to extract text from any screenshot images of android phone (I just took the example of ipad as thats the 1st thing i saw online)!! Now, the android phone has only a limited amount of text, but those texts have various colors and its really hard to find those texts with font color that match background!! Images like http://www.technixupdate.com/wp-content/uploads/images/TurnOnUSBDebuggingModeInNexusOneorOtherA_CED1/settings_thumb.png !! Is it possible to train tesseract by any chance... meaning have only limited set of words in its dictionary... just a suggestion

Comment: Yes, you can train Tesseract since version 2.00: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Answer (score 7):

Do not artificially limit yourself to just evaluate one or two methods when you manipulate your input image. You seem to only use `-blur` and `-scale` right now.

You should also consider to use the following operations:

- `-contrast`
- `-despeckle`
- `-edge`
- `-negate`
- `-normalize`
- `-posterize`
- `-type grayscale`
- `-monochrome`
- `-gamma`
- `-antialias / +antialias`

`Input Image:` [image: Original screenshot]

See for example what this command produces:

```
convert 03-Word-Collage-iPad.jpeg             \
    -scale 1000%                              \
    -blur 1x65535 -blur 1x65535 -blur 1x65535 \
    -contrast                                 \
    -normalize                                \
    -despeckle -despeckle                     \
    -type grayscale                           \
    -sharpen 1                                \
    -posterize 3                              \
    -negate                                   \
    -gamma 100                                \
    -compress zip                             \
     a.tif
```

`Output Image:` [image: Output Image]
(Sorry, when uploading a TIFF to this website it gets auto-converted to PNG. So you don't really get my TIFF when downloading the image you see above -- but you'll nevertheless see a close-enough picture of my real result.)

**Note 1:** I tested this with this ImageMagick version:

```
convert -version
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-9 2012-05-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  Features:
```

**Note 2:** Older or newer versions of ImageMagick may behave differently, especially when it comes to `-posterize`!

And this is the result of Tesseract's OCR for `a.tif`:

```
tesseract a.tif OUT  &&  cat OUT.txt

Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
   Page 0
   Text
   Common words Remove English words >
   Exclude numbers
   Word case Don't change 1+
   Theme & Layout
   Color theme London Spring >
   Font Rough Trad >
   Word layout Half and Half >
   Orientation
   Landscape
   Q
   u
   -0
   "H
   I
```

---

### Update:

I verified that the most recent version of ImageMagick `6.7.9-0` (released yesterday) does not produce the same exact result as I showed with above command + screenshot (made with version `6.7.6-9`). Here is the difference:

[image]

In any case, I'm sure if you tweak my command a bit, playing with various parameters, you'll get it to work for you, whatever your ImageMagick version is...

Comment: What impact does -contrast and -normalize give on the image and OCR's capability to read them ?
Can you suggest imageMagic preprocess for following pdf

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44235928/sample_rotate-0.pdf


I tried

convert -rotate 90 -geometry 10000 -depth 8 -density 800 sample.pdf img_800_10000.tif

Comment: @piyush: You should ask your own separate question about `-contrast` and `-normalize`. As for your *sample_rotate-0.pdf* -- wasn't there a separate question already? I think I saw one, but can't find it anymore...